# Selenium: pageLoadTimeout not working for constantly redirecting sites

Tags: firefox, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, remotewebdriver

I use Selenium to browse multiple websites and store their markup.

In order to speed things up, I have set a pageLoadTimeout to throw an exception for sites that take too long to load:

```
driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

However, this seems not to work for websites that are constantly redirecting. As an example, take this site: https://www.pickupthevalues.com/SignUp.aspx.

Is there a way to get a timeout for such sites? I do not care about the content, I just want to be able to return from my `driver.get(url)` statement.

Comment: if you are just storing markup, then you should use something faster, like simple `cURL`. unless of course you are actually interacting with elements on the page. then selenium is fine

Comment: The reason I use Selenium is because I want the markup how it is presented to the user. This may be significantly different than just using cURL due to JS/AJAX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can wait untill js return page complete status.

```
private WebDriverWait wait;

try
{
   wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60));                
   wait.Until(driver1 => ((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("return document.readyState").Equals("complete"));
}
catch(Exception ex)
{}
```